# How to save filtered data

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello everyone I am in need of assistance in this vba code for microsoft access that I am trying to make. I am trying to filter data from a table using vba the way I have it set up so far is whenever a certain event occurs have the user input a value in to the field to filter for that column of data such as for "First Name" or "Last Name". My problem is whenever I try to filter multiple fields it will not save the filtered data from the previous field that I have filtered. For instance if I filtered data for the first name 
such as James I would get a table with all the people who the first name as James but afterwards when I filter the last name in this case I used Bell it only looks for people with the last name Bell instead of looking for people with the name "James Bell" because I already specified the First Name.

```
Private Sub txtFirstName_Click()

'adds and input box to prompt the user to input the field
first = InputBox("Input Last Name")
'uses the filter feature to pick data source you want to filter such as FirstName
Me.Filter = "FirstName = """ & first & """"

**If Me.Filter = "" Then
Me.Filter = "FirstName = """ & first & """"
Else
Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND FirstName = """ & first & """"
End If**

FilterOn = True

End Sub

Private Sub txtLastName_Click()

last = InputBox("Input Last Name")
Me.Filter = "LastName = """ & last & """"

**If Me.Filter = "" Then
Me.Filter = "LastName = """ & last & """"
Else
Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND LastName = """ & last & """"
End If**

FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added a modified version of the code up top if someone can take a look at it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the filter in both routines. Instead, you want to keep the old filter and append " AND ..." it. Make sure that you include spaces around the AND. If there's no current filter, you'll need to skip the AND.

```
Private Sub txtFirstName_Click()

'adds and input box to prompt the user to input the field
first = InputBox("Input Last Name")
'uses the filter feature to pick data source you want to filter such as FirstName
If Me.Filter = "" Then
    Me.Filter = "FirstName = """ & first & """"
Else
    Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND FirstName = """ & first & """"
End If

FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub txtLastName_Click()

last = InputBox("Input Last Name")
If Me.Filter = "" Then
    Me.Filter = "LastName = """ & last & """"
Else
    Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND LastName = """ & last & """"
End If

FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I implemented the code that you have suggested but it hasnt done anything different When I use the first and last name as James Bell I am suppose to get 7 results from the table with that name but at the top I get 3 with the same results and the rest are at the bottom which you have to go search for. This means that it is still not saving my last filtered data. I dont know if I am using the code provided the wrong way I will edit my original post to incorporate your code so you can see.

Comment: Can someone shine some light on this issue?

Comment: I've updated my post to show where to put the code. Can you press Ctrl-G and then type `? Forms(0).Filter` to see what is actually being held in the filter at various times? I'd also recommend you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. This will make you declare all variables, but it will help find anything that is mis-spelled. I wonder if changing `FilterOn = True` to `Me.FilterOn = True` would make any difference.

Comment: I have actualy tried that format of the code before you answered again. But when I did it that way and I input a field value it could not find any matches even thought there are matches within the table. But as you requested my values are being read ? Forms(0).Filter
LastName="bell" And LastName="bell" And FirstName="james" And LastName="bell" And FirstName="james" And LastName="monroe" And LastName="bell" And LastName="bell" And FirstName="james" And

Comment: I see. Now the filter is building up, but to a fault. You are going to need to clear that filter out at some point -- including LastName="bell" AND LastName="monroe" means that you'll find no matches at all. I would create a button that sets Me.Filter = "".

Comment: I have tried what you have said and it works properly but I believe doing it this way would be inefficient because that means if the user inputs a second field in to the same text box without refiltering then the search will not work properly. Is there a way where I can write a piece of code which says "if new input value then erase the last value"

Comment: So, you want to accumulate conditions on the filter when you add LastName and FirstName (original problem) but replace a condition if it is already part of the filter. That's trickier and is beyond the sope of the original question.

Comment: I have added a modified version of the code up top if someone can take a look at it would be great.